# Can you sell an app as an in app purchase?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

From Apples site about In-App purchases: "Content includes digital books, magazines, photos, artwork, game levels, game characters, and other digital content that can be delivered within your application."

I can't find a definitive answer on this.

My question is can you sell an entire app within an app as an in-app purchase?

For example:  Company X develops App X.  Company Y develops App Y.  Can Company Y sell App X as an in-app purchase within App Y?

I'd also like to know about Android, too.

Comment: Why is this marked with Android when all you talk about is Apple?

Comment: For selling entire apps from another app in Apple App Store the answer is: NO. If your app would be kind of meta-app (holding other apps) it would technicaly be possible but wouldn't get trough approval proccess. You can always have a link to your other apps in App Store though.

Answer (score 2):

"content that can be delivered within your application"

Since you cannot deliver "an app" within your application, the answer is, simply: no.

(Apple provides no API for delivering apps)

Alternatively, if you read it as: "I'm going to build my own mini-App store inside my app", that comes under a different part of the Apple criteria, which say you are specifically not allowed to build anything that looks or feels like an App Store.

So, again: no.